# How can I differentiate between values in lower end of colorbar spectrum? (sns heatmap)

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I have a sns clustermap outlined below.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
sns.clustermap(df2,cmap='icefire', center=18, fmt=".3f", linewidths=0.05, annot=True)
```

But I have some really small values (e.g. 0.6) that are just above 0 and that are all getting coloured the same way. I played around with `vmax` and `vmin` and also used a diverging colormap but I cant seem to get them to stand out more than they do. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

**Update**
I used `z_score = 0` as a parameter to normalise around 0, seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the significance of the data and their distribution, you could work with a logarithmic or a diverging norm. The parameters could be like this:

```py
mport numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import seaborn as sns

N = 20
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.uniform(0, 0.6, N) * np.random.choice([1, 50], N),
                    'col2': np.random.uniform(0, 0.6, N) * np.random.choice([1, 50], N),
                    'col3': np.random.uniform(0, 0.6, N) * np.random.choice([1, 50], N)
                    })
norm = mcolors.LogNorm()
#norm = mcolors.DivergingNorm(vmin=0, vcenter=0.6, vmax=30)
sns.clustermap(df2, cmap='icefire', norm=norm,
               center=18, fmt=".3f", linewidths=0.05, annot=True, figsize=(10, 6))
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between this and normalising rows using ```z_score=0```?

Comment: z_score=0 means every row gets normalized between 0 and 1. This is interesting to compare values inside a row, but not so to see the relative values inside a column. So, it depends on what you need from these specific data. Optionally you can combine both approaches.